# jconsole memory tab

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I am connecting to remote jboss server with jconsole. For some reason all tabs except MBean are disabled, how can I setup jboss run configuration to allow remote memory monitoring?

I am connecting to jboss with the following link (I have taken it from jboss startup log):

```
service:jmx:rmi://hostAddr/jndi/rmi://hostAddr:1190/jmxconnector
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**

Java version on the server (there is application running which I want to monitor):

```
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
```

Java version on client (I start jconsole here):

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Any chance this is the incorrect port?  I've seen similar patterns when I've connected to the JMX "server" port instead of the "registry" port.  Complete guess.

Comment: @antispam, added java version

Comment: @Muky, unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problems.

Solution is

Set JBoss Java Options for example:

```
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
```

Environment variables

- "TEMP" and
- "TMP"

need to be set manually to an empty directory (i.e. C:\Temp). If this is not done, the tabs Memory, Threads ... are disabled.

JConsole needs to be started with the same user as the JVM. This could be "system".

This can be done with psexec

```
    PsExec.exe -s -i "%java_home%\bin\jconsole.exe"
```

Then connect to "localhost:9999"